# How to accelerate the following procedure mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT t1.accountid, t1.accountbalance
FROM transactionstable t1
WHERE transactiondate = (SELECT MAX(transactiondate)
            FROM transactionstable
            WHERE accountid = t1.accountid);
```

Is there any way to replace the second select for example using having clause, how to do because I need it to be fast (accountid is a foreign key) and transactiondate has an index on it.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use self `JOIN` with the maxima of date  per `accountid` group  instead of subquery

```
SELECT t1.accountid, 
t1.accountbalance    
FROM transactionstable t1
JOIN (SELECT accountid ,MAX(transactiondate) transactiondate
            FROM transactionstable
            GROUP BY accountid ) t
USING (transactiondate ,accountid )
```

Also a compound index on `transactiondate ,accountid` will be helpfull

```
create index my_idx on my_table(transactiondate ,accountid);
```

Comment: I have the following error:\n Unknown column 'transactiondate' in 'having clause'
\n i copied the column name from the table + i tried t1.transactiondate but the same error appears

Comment: @user3518239 see my updated answer you have used previous version of my answer

Comment: I still need your help because (transactiondate,accountid) aren't unique, so I posted it in another question thank you: [here is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105757/how-to-correct-this-query-in-mysql-its-giving-me-the-first-transaction-when-im)