# how to correct this query in mysql it's giving me the first transaction when Im using MAX

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT a.accountid,a.accountname, IFNULL(accountbalance,0)
FROM transactionstable tt
JOIN (SELECT accountid ,MAX(transactiondate) transactiondate
        FROM transactionstable 
        WHERE transactiondate<"2014-04-16"
        GROUP BY accountid ) t
USING (transactiondate ,accountid )
RIGHT JOIN allaccounts a  ON (tt.accountid=a.accountid)
GROUP BY a.accountid
ORDER BY a.accountname ;
```

I have many transactions where (transactiondate ,accountid) so its not unique, i need the last transaction (transactionid is unique) but i dont know where to add it to have for example:

```
trnx id        accountid             date              accbalance
  1               222              2014-04-16            2000
  2               222              2014-04-16            1900
  3               222              2014-04-16            1850
  4 ...
```

so I need to get the last balance: 1850 while im getting the first balance 2000 :/

thank you so much for your help

*EDIT*

i got the correct answer but its taking too much time (37secs because the table contains around 4millions records):

```
SELECT a.accountid,a.accountname, IFNULL(accountbalance,0)
FROM transactionstable tt
JOIN (SELECT accountid ,MAX(transactiondate) transactiondate,MAX(transactionid) transactionid
        FROM transactionstable
        WHERE transactiondate<"2014-04-15 23:59:59" 
        GROUP BY accountid
        HAVING MAX(transactiondate) ) t
USING ( transactionid )
RIGHT JOIN allaccounts a  ON (tt.accountid=a.accountid)
ORDER BY a.accountname ;
```

Comment: Is `transactionid` *guaranteed* to always increase, such that later transactions always have greater values?  If so, you can simply use that column instead of `transactiondate` within yoru derived table `t`.

Comment: No thats why i didn't use it :/

Comment: Then how can you hope to identify which is the "last transaction"?

Comment: you're right but the transactions should be ordered by date but from many months an error has occurred in the system so many transactions wasn't added to the transactions table so we had to add them manually at the end of the table .. and there wasn't at that time too much online users like now so there wasn't any accounts who do transactions at the same time. thank you for your comment and you are right to think that way :)

Comment: @user3518239 that query (in your edit) i have suggested but got downvoted so i have to remove my answer

Comment: I didn't see your answer .. before u deleted it :/ anyway thank you :) It's the best way for now

Comment: For any given date, is the trnx_id guaranteed to increase within that date for subsequent transactions?

Answer (score 0):

You can more easily do this logic using the `not exists` method of getting the last transaction:

```
SELECT a.accountid, a.accountname, IFNULL(accountbalance,0)
FROM allaccounts a LEFT JOIN
     transactionstable tt
     ON tt.accountid = a.accountid
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM transactionstable tt2
                  WHERE tt2.accountid = tt2.accountid and
                        (tt2.transactiondate > tt.transactiondate or
                         tt2.transactiondate = tt.transactiondate and
                         tt2.trans_id > tt.trans_id
                        )
                 )
ORDER BY a.accountname;
```

EDIT:

If you can just use `transactionid`, then try this:

```
SELECT a.accountid, a.accountname, IFNULL(accountbalance,0)
FROM allaccounts a LEFT JOIN
     transactionstable tt
     ON tt.accountid = a.accountid
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM transactionstable tt2
                  WHERE tt2.accountid = tt.accountid and
                        tt2.transactionid > tt.transactionid
                 )
ORDER BY a.accountname;
```

And, also create an index on `transactiontable(accountid, transactionid)`.

Comment: As from comments OP cleared that trans_id is not always greater there may be a scenario that `trans_id` 3 comes before `trans_id` 2 so then OP need row with `trans_id` 2 so i guess this method will not guarantee the last row per  `accountid` group as eggyal's last comment is clear there is no way to identify the last transaction

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid . . . I interpreted the comment to mean that, although the transaction ids might not increase overall, the goal is get the biggest one for the latest date.  That might not be the biggest one for the transaction id overall.

Comment: I tried it,.. I waited around 4min and the result didn't get the result because my tables are large. so i had to stop the query to do not affect the online users. but thank you for your answer :)

Comment: 1027173 ms ... till now so i have to stop it !! its very slow .. :( anyway thank you so for trying to help me :)

Comment: @twiry . . . I had a typo in the subquery in the edited version.  It might work now.